# validating checkbox acceptance for a form that doesn't have a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation

I would like to add a validator to a checkbox, so that if it is not accepted the form will not be sent. Ideally it would be a Rails solution.

The form is emailed directly to the admin as opposed to being stored in the db, so, in my limited rails wisdom I would assume model validations will not work.

Here is the part of the form concerned with the validation.

```
<%= f.check_box :agree, {}, 'Agree', "Don't Agree" %>
```

EDIT

I had tried adding

```
 validates :agree, acceptance: true
```

but with this is my model, wether accepted or not, the form keeps failing

Thanks in Advance

Rico

Comment: Try with this `validates :agree, acceptance: true`

Comment: Can you explain "the form keeps failing"? Did you get any errors?

Comment: that the form must be accepted, the thing i am trying to validate. It fails everytime wether it is checked or not. when i say fail i mean it doesnt pass the validations

Comment: Ok.Try with this `validates :agree, :acceptance => {:accept => true}`

Comment: this still doesn't work. I tried this from other threads